# Windows Command What does /s means?

Tags: windows

Waht does **/s** means in %SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc **/s**?

Where can I find the complete reference?

Thanks.

Comment: I say this belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, MMC used to have a splash screen, and the /s switch would suppress it.  The continued existence of the switch on the shortcut may just be left over cruft.

Answer (score 2):

services.msc runs with mmc (Microsoft Management Console). As far as I know, there is no /s switch. Documentation for the command line switches for this program can be [found here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757725%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: In Windows XP, the default shortcut to the Services applet from Administrative tools is %SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc /s